# How can I do this in SQL/phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I made tables :

books - with columns `ID_Books` and `Name_Books`

authors - `ID_Authors` and `Name_Author`

product - `ID` and `Author` and `Book`

I need it to put in product if `ID_Books` and `ID_Authors` is same then put that id into `ID` and in `Author` put `Name_Author` with corresponding id and in `Book` put `Name_Books` with corresponding id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question right,
you can perform a join and add that result into the third table.

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT(ID,Author,Book) 
SELECT Id_Author, Name_Author, Name_Books 
FROM AUTHOR INNER JOIN BOOKS ON Id_Author = Id_Books;
```

Comment: You have no idea how much you helped me! THIS IS SO EASY! THANK YOU!